# Scrapy install error on OS X Mavricks

Tags: python, scrapy

Getting an error when installing scrapy. Any advice? Here is the error:

```
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools,
tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/4c/znnkwgfj68l4665x2_h5lb200000gn/T/pip_build_user/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize,
'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__,
'exec'))" install --record
/var/folders/4c/znnkwgfj68l4665x2_h5lb200000gn/T/pip-EsRnnp-record/install-record.txt
--single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in
/private/var/folders/4c/znnkwgfj68l4665x2_h5lb200000gn/T/pip_build_user/lxml
```

Comment: do you have `lxml` installed?

Comment: Get another error when I try to install lxml: Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/4c/znnkwgfj68l4665x2_h5lb200000gn/T/pip_build_user/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/4c/znnkwgfj68l4665x2_h5lb200000gn/T/pip-AITDhx-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/4c/znnkwgfj68l4665x2_h5lb200000gn/T/pip_build_user/lxml

Comment: to be honest I haven't seen such error before. Have you tried to install them via `pip`?

Comment: Yes, I tried pip and easy_install

Comment: it seems `lxml` requires `libxslt` and `libxml2` according to [doc](http://lxml.de/installation.html). Could you try to make sure you have them?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, on amazon linux, trying to install scrapy with pip, for python 2.6.9, 2.7.5 and 3.4.1.

I'm not sure if any other libraries were also needed, but it was after I installed these first that the scrapy installation passed:

```
yum -y install libxml2-devel libxslt-devel
pip install scrapy
```

(I also had `libxml2-python` and `libffi-devel` installed from earlier attempts).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using brew install python first.